# Git: sometimes a pull shows large number of bytes but no changes

Tags: git, visual-studio

We have a large project in Git.  Sometimes when a teammember does a pull, Visual Studio will show a large number of bytes coming down (like a 100MB sometimes), but then report no changes.  What can cause that?

Better, what are some things that I can do to diagnose it?

Comment: For example commit some 100MB file, then `revert` (_not_ reset I mean) commit

Comment: So here's a weird example.  I did a fetch a little while ago.  I showed 148MB coming down, but then said no changes -- there aren't even any new commits in my local repo (the revert would have looked like a commit, wouldn't it?)

Comment: If you have provided some `git fetch` or `git pull` results according what have changed, it would be much clearer

Answer (score 2):

A pull will do a fetch first, and then a merge. A fetch may contain changes that affect branches other than the one you are working in. So you may see the content come down, but have no changes *in your branch*.

Remember, with git, every copy of the repository is a *full* copy, so you will have all of the changes in all branches stored locally on your disk, whether you work with those branches or not.

Here's an example of git command-line output from a random repo I pulled:

```
From github.com:docker/docker
   31b882e..2fb442f  master     -> origin/master
   86b0d3c..d38a598  docs       -> origin/docs
 + 11a9c45...e72d897 release/1.8 -> origin/release/1.8  (forced update)
```

I am on master currently in this repo, but it pulled content changes in the docs branch, and added a new branch. This output is truncated, it also added a few other branches. But if I had been in some new branch I made up and nobody had committed to that branch, I would have seen no changes in my own workspace, even though I downloaded a few MB of stuff from the upstream repository.

Comment: That might explain some of this.  What about tagging?  Our build server applies tags throughout the day for each build.

Comment: Tags consume some space, but you would need to add quite a lot of tags to get to 100MB+.

Comment: "very copy of the repository is a full copy" ... unless it is shallow copy